# Append to the same list

Tags: python

I am from a solid C/C++ background, so please bear with me if my question is silly.

Here I have two classes that declared to encapsulate data,

```
class Node:
    Term = ""
    TermInfo = []
    def __init__(self,S,Info):
        self.Term = S
        self.TermInfo.append(Info)

class TermInfo:
    DocID = 0
    Freq = 0
    def __init__(self,ID,F):
        self.DocID = ID
        self.Freq = F
```

and I was trying to manipulate them this way

```
 Info = TermInfo(ID,0)
 node = Node(j,Info)
 Dict[j] = node
```

Basically I was trying to construct a dictionary that contains nodes that are made of a string "Term" and a list of "Terminfo", I was expecting that each node has its own copy. However, after I called the three lines twice in a row

```
Info = TermInfo(ID,0)
node = Node(j,Info)
Dict[j] = node

Info = TermInfo(ID,0)
node = Node(j,Info)
Dict[j] = node
```

I was surprised to see that the two lists of "TermInfo" were pointing to the same memory address and the second append() also changed the first list,So how do I make sure each node has its own copy instead of pointing to the same address? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

create a new list in `__init__`.

```
def __init__(self,S,Info):
    self.Term = S
    self.TermInfo = [Info]
```

Long answer:

This has to do with how python looks up attributes.  When you do:  `instance.attribute`, python first looks for the attribute on the instance.  If it's not found there, it looks for the attribute on the **class**.  Here you have a list attribute on the class and you keep on appending to that attribute via the instance.  So when you have the line:

```
self.TermInfo.append(whatever)
```

Python first looks at self.  however, `self` doesn't have a `TermInfo` attribute, so then python looks at `self.__class__` (`Node` in this case) for the `TermInfo` attribute -- and it finds it so it appends to the `Node.TermInfo` list.

Answer (score 0):

Only attributes assigned in `__init__` and after object construction are instance attributes. Attributes assigned in the class definition are class attributes, similar to static class members in other languages. So if you want to have a per-instance attribute, assign its initial value in `__init__`.